# system loadLibrary hangs when used in multiple threads

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, java-native-interface, loadlibrary

I'm trying to load a native library from a Java app in threads, say each thread Thread1, Thread2 ... ThreadN tries to load the same shared library but, after the Thread1 has loaded the library other threads are blocked on the System.loadLibrary. can anyone please help me how to fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use synchronization and flag:

```
boolean isLoaded = false;
Object lock = new Object();

void loadLibs(){
    sinchronized(lock){
        if(!isLoaded) {
            //System.loadLibrary ...
            isLoaded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

or else you can use trick wih static constructor which guaranteed to be invoked only once

```
static {
    //System.loadLibrary ...
}
```

Comment: Runtime.loadLibrary0 (which is where System.loadLibrary leads) is already synchronized against a singleton, and it contains a list of all previously loaded libraries which is used to prevent double loading.  The Java Doc on Runtime also states 'If this method is called more than once with the same library name, the second and subsequent calls are ignored.'.  So it will be interesting to see if your suggestion fixes the problem, if it does then it will look like a bug in the JVM libs.

Comment: re 'trick wih static constructor which guaranteed to be invoked only once'; that is not entirely true.  It is guaranteed to be invoked only once per class loader that loads the class.  In most environments the two statements are equal, however it is a good cause of confusion in environments with multiple class loaders.  A minor tweak to the line will fix that statement.

Comment: Thanks to Talex and Chris K, My design requirement is load the library in the separate threads which creates different instance to load the library. since i thought that if the lib is already loaded then the call will return, but i see some race in System.loadLibrary.

Comment: @parthi_for_tech if you are confident that this is a problem lower down in the stack and can narrow it down to a small and complete test case, repost it here and also consider approaching one of the Oracle dev lists with it.  If there is a problem lower down in the stack, then they will be able to advise.  You may have made a mistake at the native level that has thrown it.

Comment: @parthi_for_tech; ps not all 'requirements' are created equal ;)  I agree with Talex' suggestion of limiting the call to once only.  However what you had should have worked, so there is something 'bad' going on that we cannot deduce from the contents of the current question.